# Checkout loader keeps loading in Magento ver. 2.3.5-p1

Tags: javascript, css, .htaccess, magento-2.3

Theme version: Argento Theme for Magento 2

Expected results: After click on checkout button, checkout page should be open.

Received result: Checkout loader keeps loading, after a click on proceed to the checkout page.

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.